# Execute command on VZ container start and stop

Tags: virtual-machine, openvz, proxmox

Is there any way of executing a console command on the host machine when a specific VZ container is started (and/or stopped)? Something like in the `/etc/network/interfaces` where you can specify an on `up` and on `down` command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can setup the cron on your VPS to start the network service. You will have to setup the cron @reboot on your VPS.